# Open systems (Conservation of Energy): is a temperature change possible if a tube is thermally isolated?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, flow

Full question: consider an perfectly thermally isolated cylinder. Water is flowing through this cylinder from the entry to the exit. Is it possible for the water flowing through the exit to have a **lower temperature** than the water flowing through the entry of the tube ?

Comment: Is this a homework question? I don't have any idea why you think there is any doubt about the correct answer.

Comment: In the context of your question, what does "thermally isolated" mean?  Does it mean _adiabatic_ (no heat transfer)? Or does it mean constant temperature? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have water coming out be colder than the water going in.

Imagine a big pipe connecting a big container of ice water to a big container of boiling water.

Then one end starts out colder than the other. Now raise the container of boiling water higher up so that water starts to flow from the boiling water to the freezing water.

Heat diffuses from the hotter water to the colder water and it is perfectly capable of transferring at a speed greater than the flow speed, so the traveling water literally gets colder as it travels from one end to the other because it is heating the water in front of it ad it travels.

In the frame of the water, heat is diffusing from the hotter water to the colder water. So the hotter water is getting colder. Therefore when the tube passes over it the second time it can be colder than when the other end of the tube passed over it.